# BootStrap not formatting view in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC 5 application that I created with bootstrap.  Now I had to create an MVC 4 application and copied my _layout.cshtml file over to it and made the modifications that I needed.  I, further, added bootstrap to the project.  However, my menu bar is not showing up.  All I get is this pic:

[image]

This is kind of what I was expecting.  (this is a pic of the app I copied the code from):

[image]

Here is my _layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    @*<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>*@
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Interactive Courses", "Index", "PTEInteractiveCourse")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Tracking Classes", "Index", "PTETrackingClass")</li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() Securities Training Corporation. All rights reserved.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you checked if bootstrap css and jquery was loaded correctly? Does it right configured in your bundles?

Comment: You mean through developer tools? yes there was no error, unless you are talking about somewhere else.

Comment: @RicardoPontual I already added it to my bundleconfig.cs

Comment: Just for a test, try to load jquery and bootstrap inside head tag, below modernizr.

Comment: @RicardoPontual same issue after trying that.

Comment: simple test would be to add a `<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Test</a>` to your view and see if it looks a button.. if not then you're not loading bootstrap css.   Pretty sure that MVC4 did not include bootstrap.css in the `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` bundle

Comment: @JamieD77, you are correct it did not show up as a button. It was just a link with the word test and a line under it.  How do I add it so it loads bootstrap then?

Comment: just drag the bootstrap.css file from the content folder that it's in, to your _layout <head> section..